# Perform query on existing SQL result? Find result from subset of SQL result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a script that goes through all order history. It takes several minutes to print the results, but I noticed I perform several SQL statements that are similar enough I wonder if you could do another query on an existing SQL result.

For example:

```
-- first SQL request
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE status = 'shipped'
```

Then, in a foreach loop, I want to find information from this result. My naive approach is to perform these three queries. Note the similarity to the query above.

```
-- grabs customer's LTD sales
SELECT SUM(total) FROM orders
WHERE user = :user
AND status = 'shipped'    

-- grabs number of orders customer has made
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders
WHERE user = :user
AND status = 'shipped'
AND total != 0

-- grabs number of giveaways user has won
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders
WHERE user = :user
AND status = 'shipped'
AND total = 0
```

I end up querying the same table several times when the results I seek are subsets of the first query. I'd like to get information from the first query without performing more SQL calls. Some pseudocode:

```
$stmt1 = $db->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM orders
    WHERE status = 'shipped'
");
$stmt1->execute();

foreach($stmt1 as $var) {
    $username = $var['username'];

    $stmt2 = $stmt1->workOn("
        SELECT SUM(total) FROM this
        WHERE user = :user
    ");
    $stmt2->execute(array(
        ':user' => $username
    ));
    $lifesales = $stmt2->fetchColumn();

    $stmt3 = $stmt1->workOn("
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM this
        WHERE user = :user
        AND total != 0
    ");
    $stmt3->execute(array(
        ':user' => $username
    ));
    $totalorders = $stmt3->fetchColumn();

    $stmt4 = $stmt1->workOn("
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM this
        WHERE user = :user
        AND total = 0
    ");
    $stmt4->execute(array(
        ':user' => $username
    ));
    $totalgaws = $stmt4->fetchColumn();

    echo "Username: ".$username;
    echo "<br/>Lifetime Sales: ".$lifesales;
    echo "<br/>Total Orders: ".$totalorders;
    echo "<br/>Total Giveaways: ".$totalgaws;
    echo "<br/><br/>";
}
```

Is something like this possible? Is it faster? My existing method is slow and ugly, I'd like a quicker way to do this.

Comment: You can store the result of a query in a temporary table, then do additional queries on that table to perform further filtering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could do one pass through the table to get all three aggregates for all users:

```
SELECT s.user
     , SUM(s.total)        AS `ltd_sales`
     , SUM(s.total <> 0)   AS `cnt_prior_sales`
     , SUM(s.total  = 0)   AS `cnt_giveaways`
  FROM orders s
 WHERE s.status = 'shipped'
 GROUP
    BY s.user
```

That's going to be expensive on large sets. But if we are needing that for all orders, for all users, that's likely going to be faster than doing separate correlated subqueries.

An index with leading column of `user` is going to allow MySQL to use the index for the `GROUP BY` operation. Including the `status` and `total` columns in the index will allow the query to be satisfied entirely from the index. (With the equality predicate on `status` column, we could also try an index with `status` as the leading column, followed by `user` column, then followed by `total`.

If we only need this result for a small subset of users e.g. we are fetching only the first 10 rows from the first query, then running a separate query is likely going to be faster. We'd just incorporate the condition `WHERE s.user = :user` into the query, as in the original code. But run just the one query rather than three separate queries.

---

We can combine that with the first query by making it into an inline view, wrapping it in parens and putting into the `FROM` clause as a row source

```
SELECT o.*

     , t.ltd_sales
     , t.cnt_prior_sale
     , t.cnt_giveaways

  FROM orders o 

  JOIN ( 
         SELECT s.user
              , SUM(s.total)        AS `ltd_sales`
              , SUM(s.total <> 0)   AS `cnt_prior_sales`
              , SUM(s.total  = 0)   AS `cnt_giveaways`
           FROM orders s
          WHERE s.status = 'shipped'
          GROUP
             BY s.user
      ) t
   ON t.user = o.user 

WHERE o.status = 'shipped'
```

---

I'm not sure about that column named "prior" sales... this is returning all shipped orders, without regard to comparing any dates (order date, fulfillment date, shipment date), which we would typically associate with a concept of what "prior" means.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

noticing that the question is modified, removing the condition "`status = 'shipped'`" from the count of all orders by the user...

I will note that we can move conditions from the `WHERE` clause into the conditional aggregates.

Not that all these results are needed by OP, but as a demonstration...

```
SELECT s.user
     , SUM(IF(s.status='shipped',s.total,0))       AS `ltd_sales_shipped`
     , SUM(IF(s.status<>'shipped',s.total,0))       AS `ltd_sales_not_shipped`

     , SUM(s.status='shipped' AND s.total <> 0)   AS `cnt_shipped_orders`
     , SUM(s.status='canceled')                   AS `cnt_canceled`

     , SUM(s.status='shipped' AND s.total  = 0)   AS `cnt_shipped_giveaways`
  FROM orders s
 GROUP
    BY s.user
```

Comment: I think you have some typos in your code: `SUM(s.total <> 0) AS cnt_prior_sales` should probably be a `COUNT()`. Same for the other one...

Comment: Not a typo. *conditional aggregation* That's MySQL shorthand. The expression `s.total <> 0` is going to be evaluated for each row, and return 1 (for true), 0 (for false) or NULL. Getting a SUM() of that expression is the same as getting a count of the rows where that condition is true. More portable ANSI-standards compliant version `SUM(CASE WHEN s.total <> 0 THEN 1 WHEN s.total = 0 THEN 0 ELSE NULL END)`

Comment: Thank you for the response. In regards to your edit, the `status = 'shipped'` is still there, just only in `stmt1`. The other queries are made off of `stmt1` in my pseudocode, so `status = 'shipped'` is implied.

Comment: @gator: i failed to answer the question you asked... once `stmt1` is executed, no, its not possible to run a query against the results of `stmt1`. it is possible to materialize that set, either as a temporary table, or as a derived table (wrap the SQL in parens, and reference that in place of a table in the FROM clause). The outer query (in the same SQL statement) can query from the derived table. But that doesn't address getting aggregates (counts) *and* detail rows at the same time. Doing the aggregation in an inline view lets those rows be "matched" to detail rows in an outer query.

Comment: The followup demonstrates a more general usage of conditional aggregation... it's possible to get "overlapping" counts. For example, a count of all orders, a count of only shipped orders, with detail rows  being included in *both* counts.

Comment: Thank you. This improves the speed immensely: a few minutes down to a few seconds. I had never seen conditional aggregates before, thanks for teaching!

Comment: @gator:  Having more tools in the SQL toolbelt, and knowing how to use them, are good things.  As you have discovered, there is overhead incurred with each SQL statement we execute. And processing large sets RBAR (row by agonizing row) can lead to performance problems. With SQL, we like to think in terms of "sets"  performing operations on "sets". (Until the "sets" get too large; and we need to perform operations on smaller subsets.) And you were spot on with the idea of operating on the set returned by the first statement. We just get MySQL to do the operations, and return the single set.

Comment: @spencer7593 I'm just curious, but how would I treat null as 0 with a conditional aggregate? Consider if I implemented this on a pending orders page: they have 0 shipped orders yet I want to see "0 orders made". Right now it shows blank. `SUM(s.status = 'shipped' AND s.total <> 0)`, is there a way to treat null as 0?

Comment: @gator,  wrap the whole expression in `IFNULL( expr, 0)`.  That is equivalent to the more portable ANSI standards compliant  `CASE WHEN expr IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE expr END`  .  I use the MySQL shorthand version because I don't want to repeat expr two times.)...  `IFNULL( SUM(s.status  = 'shipped' AND s.total <> 0) ,0) AS ...`

Answer (score 1):

Once the results are returned from the database, you can not run an SQL on top of them. However you can store them in a temporary table, to reuse them.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

You need to create a temporary table, and insert all the data from the select statement, and then you can run queries on that table. Not sure if it would help much in your case.

For your particular case you can do something like:

```
select user, (total = 0) as is_total_zero, count(*), sum(total) 
from orders
where status = 'shipped'
group by user, total = 0
```

However you would have to do some additional summing to get the results of the second query which gives you the sums per user, as they would be divided into two different groups with a different is_total_zero value.